# Multiple AND/OR logic messed up

Tags: mysql

I need to get my data when `userID=4` and status= In use or Pending or Deleted.
But I am getting extra data not sure why.

I am getting extra data from

```
userid=3
```

MySQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `registered_bicycle` 
WHERE (`userID`='4') 
  AND (`status`='In Use') 
  OR (`status`='Pending') 
  OR (`status`='Deleted')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `registered_bicycle`
WHERE `userID` = '4'
AND `status` IN('In Use','Pending','Deleted')
```

Your `and/or` logic got mixed up because of lacking proper parentheses. Also you can use `IN` instead of multiple OR clauses.

<sub>**Btw**, `IN` is just the short form of `OR`</sub>

Comment: Thank You, I have understand my mistake. Learn some thing new

Comment: You are welcome. And be careful while using multiple `and/or` logics. Must use parentheses. And you can always bypass multiple `OR` clauses by a single `IN`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `(...)` arround the `OR` Statements:

```
SELECT * FROM `registered_bicycle` 
WHERE (`userID`='4') 
  AND (`status`='In Use' 
  OR `status`='Pending' 
  OR `status`='Deleted')
```

or use `IN` function

Comment: Thank You, I have understand my mistake. Learn some thing new

Answer (score 1):

Put the part after the `AND` between braces, otherwise it will return data with `userID=4` OR `status=xy`

```
SELECT * FROM `registered_bicycle` WHERE (`userID`='4') AND (
      (`status`='In Use') 
     OR (`status`='Pending') 
     OR (`status`='Deleted')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `registered_bicycle` 
WHERE (`userID`='4') 
  AND `status`IN('In Use','Pending','Deleted')
```

Comment: Thank You, I have understand my mistake. Learn some thing new